# Is there a way to specify more precise site category in Google Search?

Tags: google-search

Is there a Google Search feature to show results from a very specific category?

For example, show only results from *software company websites*, or *social networking websites*, etc. I am aware of a few categories that Google search already offers, like images, blogs, news, etc. But, is that all we can do? Is there no way to filter results by more specific categories?

Comment: Yippy.com which was formerly Clusty.com, clusters search results by categories. If you search for "Apple", you will find results categorized under Fruit, Computers etc

Answer (score 2):

> Is there no way to filter results by more specific categories?

No, there is no way to filter by more specific categories.